# consolidate "cmd" and "cmd.exe" tags

Tags: support, retag-request

The tags [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) and [cmd.exe](/questions/tagged/cmd.exe) should be consolidated.  They refer to the exact same thing.

Please take a look.

Comment: Perhaps it should just be synonymized?  [tag:cmd] <- [tag:cmd.exe].  I can't think of any other uses of `cmd` outside of Windows.